# UK Visa document upload at VFS global

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, vfs-global

I am an Indian expat staying in Oman and have completed the visa application at gov.uk for myself and family. After making the payment at gov.uk, I was directed to vfsglobal website where I needed to upload my documents. It is really confusing. There are several tabs with the same title. further some of the tabs are not understandable. I understand that I needed to upload air ticket/hotel booking; employment/salary certificate; bank statement. Can someone guide under which specific tabs I may upload these documents.

Do I also need to upload my passport copy and the residential proof of Oman.

Appreciate your support, thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s about using VFS system and should be directed to the VFS support team.

Comment: I think it should be left open. Several of the OP's comments (identical tabs, not understandable content) could be caused by challenges in observing or reading comprehension, not website design or operation. A screenshot would be helpful to discern what's at issue.